# How to stack two divs together?

Tags: html, css

I've looked everywhere and followed everyones instructions and it's not working ;__;

```
#aside
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#39A861;
}

#section
{
    width:800px;
    float:left;
}
```

first they were a section and aside tags but I changed them to divs to ease the process but NOPE the same results. the second div is not right next to the first one, it like breaks a line
this is just driving me nuts
 my container where these two divs will be:

```
#container1
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
```

here's the html

```
<div id="container1">  
    <div id="aside">
        <h2>stuff</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <h1>stuff</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your html, please

Comment: just remove the width for aside and section. it should be next to each other. then inside aside add a new div with a width.

Comment: Make sure there are no margins and/or padding set on #aside-div and #section-div (check it in Firebug or similar). If there is a right-padding of 10px on #adisde for example the two divs would have a width of 1010px and therefore the #section-div would "go down" below the #aside-div (because it exceeds the #container1-width)

Answer (score 2):

There are so may ways to do like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="aside"><h1>Title</h1></div>
  <div class="section">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

### option 1

```
.container {
  width:1000px;
}

.aside{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}

.section {
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

### option 2

```
.container {
  width:1000px;
}

.container:before, .container:after{
  display:table;
  content:"";
}

.container:after{
  clear:both;
}

.aside{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}

.section {
  float:left;
  width:800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you probably got some `border` and/or `padding`, `margin`, or anything that is taking space in your container.

In the following example, although the container width is `200px` and inner divs got `50px` and `150px`, they won't stay in the same line because the border takes `1px` from each side:

(click "Run code snippet" to see the results)

```css
#container     { width: 200px; height: 45px; border: 1px solid #f00; }
#container div { border: 1px solid #000; }
#first         { float: left; width: 50px; }
#second        { float: left; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="first"> First div </div>
    <div id="second"> Second div </div> 
</div>
```

In this example you have two options: 1) remove the border, or 2) account for the border size reducing inner divs' size:

```css
#container     { width: 200px; height: 45px; border: 1px solid #f00; }
#container div { border: 1px solid #000; }
#first         { float: left; width: 48px; }
#second        { float: left; width: 148px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="first"> First div </div>
    <div id="second"> Second div </div> 
</div>
```

---

I suggest you playing with these css properties in [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) at `F12` till you see both of them in the same line.